# MATLAB, extracting and saving values in a vector between 0 and 5, then 5 and 10, and so on

Tags: matlab

I have a column vector of values between 0 and 180. I'm looking for a way to extract all the values as columns between 0 and 5, then all the values between 5 and 10 and so on up to 180, and then save all these into a cell array.

I'm aware that I can use this sort of technique:

```
range = data(5 <= data & data <= 10)
```

but it seems a little long winded to write this out for each range

Comment: Well you can wrap your existing code with a for loop, then use the iterator to index into `range` as well as calculate the cut-off values.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you're trying to count values in ranges, use the `hist` command.

Comment: @rlbond His boundaries are inclusive, though, which might be a little tricky with `hist`. Also, from the sample code it seems he's trying to sort into bins, so `histc` might be of use here, though I can't think of a way to deal with the inclusive bin boundaries.

Comment: My suspicion is that the inclusive bounds are unintentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward approach is to wrap your code into a for loop, something like this:

```
maxValue = 180;
data = randperm(maxValue);   %//some dummy data
binSize = 5;
numBins = maxValue / binSize;
ranges = cell(1, numBins);

for i = 1:numBins 
    ranges{i} = data(binSize  * (i - 1) <= data & data <= binSize  * i);
end
```

Comment: Hi! I've made a MATLAB chat room for us in case you wanted to discuss anything related to MATLAB that is off-topic, or if you want to discuss things that span longer than a comments block.  Stop by when you have time! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab